# Is there a way around obtaining the address of a const object

Tags: c++

I am trying to achieve the following

```
#include<iostream>                                                                             
#include <vector>                                                                              
                                                                                               
class var {                                                                                    
public:                                                                                        
    static std::vector<var*> variables_;                                                       
                                                                                               
    friend var operator-(const var& v) {                                                       
        // this is not compiling                                                               
        variables_.push_back(&v);                                                              
    }                                                                                          
};                                                                                             
                                                                                               
int main() { var x; }
```

The error

```
est.cpp: In function ‘var operator-(const var&)’:
test.cpp:10:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘push_back(const var*)’
   10 |         variables_.push_back(&v);
      |                                ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/vector:67,
                 from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_vector.h:1187:7: note: candidate: ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = var*; _Alloc = std::allocator<var*>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = var*]’ (near match)
 1187 |       push_back(const value_type& __x)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_vector.h:1187:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
test.cpp:10:30: error: invalid conversion from ‘const var*’ to ‘std::vector<var*>::value_type’ {aka ‘var*’} [-fpermissive]
   10 |         variables_.push_back(&v);
      |                              ^~
      |                              |
      |                              const var*
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/vector:67,
                 from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_vector.h:1203:7: note: candidate: ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = var*; _Alloc = std::allocator<var*>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = var*]’ (near match)
 1203 |       push_back(value_type&& __x)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_vector.h:1203:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
test.cpp:10:30: error: invalid conversion from ‘const var*’ to ‘std::vector<var*>::value_type’ {aka ‘var*’} [-fpermissive]
   10 |         variables_.push_back(&v);
      |                              ^~
      |                              |
      |                              const var*
test.cpp:11:5: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
   11 |     }
      |     ^
```

I have read several posts on this site telling me why this wont work. One of which is that elements of the vector have to be copy assignable. So I understand WHY, but I don't understand how to get around it.

There must be a way around this.

Comment: "... that elements of the vector have to be copy assignable." ? `var*` surely is copy assignable. `const var*` is too.

Comment: `var*` elements are copy-assignable, so I'm not sure you do understand why this won't work. In general, comments like "I understand why this doesn't work, but I don't understand how to get around it" suggest that you need to explain what you're _actually trying to do_, because whether or not a workaround exists and what it actually is will heavily depend on what your actual end goal is.

Comment: That's not the why. The why is provided by the compiler: "invalid conversion from ‘const var*’ to ‘std::vector<var*>::value_type’ {aka ‘var*’}".

Answer (score 8):

You take a `const var&`, but your vector stores `var*` (without the `const`). Either your vector needs to store pointers to constants

```
static std::vector<const var*> variables_;
```

or your `operator-` needs to take a non-constant reference

```
friend var operator-(var& v) { ... }
```

You should do the first thing if you never plan to modify `var` through the `variables_` vector, or the second otherwise.

Comment: Or, if you really want, use `const_cast` (but be careful).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman when the function parameter is `const var& v` you cannot tell if the object is actually `const` or not, you have to assume it is

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Sure, but if for some reason you need to store non-const objects but you never modify them you can `const_cast` them, but be careful not to modify them.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I dont see the relevance of `const_cast` here. OP is asking about the parameter to `friend var operator-(const var& v)`. Its either that or `friend var operator-(var& v)` as suggested in this answer

Comment: @ChayimFriedman In that case there would be no reason to have pointers-to-non-const. `const_cast` should never be a valid alternative because you can always convert a pointer-to-non-const to a pointer-to-const

Comment: Your solution works in my minimal working example. But in my code it is not working. giving me an undefined reference

Comment: Nothing about the suggested change should be causing an undefined reference error. It sounds like you have another issue. What has probably happened is that this code compiled and so the compiler made it further and ran into another problem.

Comment: @HMPtwo This answer assumes that the variables will live for as long as you need them to in your program. If you create a local variable and then store a pointer to it, the pointer doesn't keep the local alive. It's your job, not C++'s, to ensure the lifetimes of your variables line up, and if you're freeing data prematurely then you'll run into problems at runtime